# Can't get Angular2 component to run in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, angular

My Angular2 app runs in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but not Internet Explorer. It finds an error in angular2.min.js: `SyntaxError: Expected ';'`

Here's my HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Component</title>
    <script src="../../../../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>    
    <script src="../../../../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>    
    <script src="../../../../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="../../../../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>        
    <script>
      System.import("./app/main").catch(console.log.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-comp></my-comp>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is essentially similar to the HTML in Angular's [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), but I still get the error in IE. Any ideas?

Comment: try <script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

Comment: I tried that and I tried rearranging the scripts. No luck. The full error is: "Potentially unhandled rejection [3] SyntaxError: Expected ';'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally there is a [workaround for the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7144) (2nd comment).

What worked for me was to include the script 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js':

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```